# perspective or projection matrix

Tags: navigation, mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey!

Is there any node/pkg that already implemented the mono camera perspective matrix calculation?
I have a mono camera mounted on a fixed place and I would like to get the projection matrix. I know the camera calibration node and I thought there is something similar for this task.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193454/perspective-or-projection-matrix/) by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2014-09-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on 2014-09-25**:
You will need some assumptions to compute the projection matrix from a mono camera, like some known calibration pattern. What are your assumptions ?

**Comment by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on 2014-09-25**:
I'm going to do dhte calibration too. I know that I need the intrinsic parameters in order to get the correct perspective matrix. But is there any ready to use node for perspective matrix calculation if I supply the camera calibration files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sounds like you want to use the [image_geometry](http://wiki.ros.org/image_geometry) package. It contains convenience functionality for working with standard ROS camera models (initialized from a CameraInfo message). Specifically, the [PinholeCameraModel::fullProjectionMatrix](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/image_geometry/html/c++/classimage__geometry_1_1PinholeCameraModel.html#ac6503ef49e070ae83644fe20cc7017bb) and [PinholeCameraModel::projectPixelTo3dRay](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/image_geometry/html/c++/classimage__geometry_1_1PinholeCameraModel.html#ad52a4a71c6f6d375d69865e40a117ca3) methods sound like what you´re looking for. See also the associated [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/image_geometry/Tutorials/ProjectTfFrameToImage) for info on how to initialize things from a CameraInfo in a node.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2